# How to set formula of duplicate value in report salesforce?

Tags: reporting

I tried to make a report duplicate contact, duplicate contact happened if there is same account ID and Mobile Phone in multiple contact.

in report duplicate contact, there is duplicate_contact__c field. is it possible to set formula value true or false to check if there is duplicate contact? or i should make a process builder or flow? need your advice guys, thankyou

This is the ilustration
[image]

Comment: Stop using the community tag for things that aren't for community sites (experience sites).

Comment: What have you tried, what are you stuck on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot use a formula field for looking at sibling records.  This would need to be set using a trigger or flow upon record creation/update.

Note: If you wanted to prevent duplicates from happening, you could create a "Unique Identifier" field (String) in which you put the concatenation of the fields you want to be the key (Account ID + Mobile Phone).  (Do the concatenation in a trigger or flow.)  That would prevent duplicates from being created.